# spool/job logs for SAP foreground

Tags: logging, jobs, foreground, spool, sap-basis

Just like `SM37` exists for viewing logs and spools for background job, what exist for foreground job? I searched hard on Google and found nothing existing like this.

Little helpful things found like `ST03G` but not as purposeful as `SM37`.

Main purpose is to refer the spool and logs for foreground jobs ran in past.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: What is a "foreground job" in your definition?

Comment: The same question here...

Comment: Job which is run in foreground where SAP get locked and you have to wait until job completes. After that spool is visible on screen. But this spool is not avaialable in future once you exit